# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I get this error when I press a button that segues to another view controller. I have gone through my breakpoints for over an hour, and realized that every piece of code gets called in my `viewDidLoad` method.

What can I post to help you all figure out this error?

Here is my overriden `prepareForSegue` method:

```
if let secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as? CreateEventViewController {
        if let eventType = sender as? UIButton {
            secondScene.eventType = eventType.tag
        }
        //check if they sent data
        secondScene.onDataAvailable = {[weak self]
            (data) in
            if let _ = self {
                //add event then refresh
                DayViewViewController.eventList.append(data)
                self!.refreshEventList()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you performing this segue with a button tap or from viewDidAppear ? or which viewDidAppear crashes?

Comment: I'm performing this segue with a Button tap

Comment: The viewDidAppear doesn't crash. I'm not sure at what point the app crashes, but - in human time - instantly after viewDidAppear runs

Comment: do you have an exception breakpoint or a stack trace with an error message?

Comment: Looking at the output, I have this: `2015-07-28 22:46:45.818 virtumed-iPad-event[1742:265500] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)`

Comment: I just stopped running the app on my xcode, then closed it on my ipad, then reopened, and it works

Comment: For future reference, set an exception breakpoint. In the left menu, click the breakpoint tab of the menu (second to last tab), then the plus in the bottom left, then add exception breakpoint. This will allow you to see what line is crashing. Restarting the simulator can fix some network related issues so perhaps that is what happened for you.